# Chromedriver plugin on jenkin's selenium grid running into an error

Tags: jenkins, selenium-grid, jenkins-plugins, selenium-chromedriver

Jenkins is running on Linux and I have set up a node/slave (localhost) to run. When I don't have the chromedriver plugin, the node can run and is online. With the plugin I get an Error:

```
    Installing chromedriver to /var/jenkins/tools/chromedriver
    ERROR: Unexpected error in launching a slave. This is probably a bug in Jenkins.
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.chromedriver.DownloadableImpl.getType(DownloadableImpl.java:91)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.chromedriver.DownloadableImpl.select(DownloadableImpl.java:78)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.chromedriver.DownloadableImpl.resolve(DownloadableImpl.java:35)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.chromedriver.ComputerListenerImpl.process(ComputerListenerImpl.java:43)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.chromedriver.ComputerListenerImpl.preOnline(ComputerListenerImpl.java:34)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:370)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:317)
        at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.startSlave(SSHLauncher.java:454)
        at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.launch(SSHLauncher.java:293)
        at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:200)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
    ERROR: Connection terminated
    java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2570)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1314)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:368)
        at hudson.remoting.Command.readFrom(Command.java:90)
        at hudson.remoting.ClassicCommandTransport.read(ClassicCommandTransport.java:59)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
```

Am I doing something wrong, how do you fix this or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was reported: [JENKINS-12765](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12765)